# ListView for option list in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to insert a listview inside an AlertDialog to display some options but I'm getting an error with the constructor: ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.option_list, R.id.option, option_items);
It says cannot resolve constructor. The code is below.

```
private void LongClick() {
    myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long IDinDB) {
            Cursor res = myDb.GetRow(IDinDB);
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                long idDB = res.getLong(DatabaseHelper.ROWID);
            }

            String[] option_items = {"Delete"};
            ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.option_list, R.id.option, option_items);
            optionList.setAdapter(adapter);
            optionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
                    TextView txt = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.option);
                    Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this, txt.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });

            return true;
        }

    });

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `this` it means the current object instance class you write in. When you wrote `new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()` you create a new anonymous class, so the word `this` inside its methods will refer to this newly created class object. ArrayAdapter needs `context` instance in constructor, not a `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`. So you need to reference the context object. You can get it:

a) from method parameter `viewClicked` object (`viewClicked.getContext()`)

or

b) as 
     `ViewActivity.this` as you did in `onItemClick`